# LINQ grouping and selecting into properties

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I'm still trying to get the hang of LINQ and am having trouble with this.  I have a `List<Data>` like so:

```
GroupId|SectionId|Content
-------------------------
      1|        3|part1-2
      1|        7|part1-1
      3|        3|part3-2
      1|        1|part1-3
      3|        1|part3-3
      3|        7|part3-1
```

I would like to convert it to `IEnumerable<AnonymousType>` where each `AnonymousType` represents one `GroupId` and each property is linked to a specific `SectionId`.  In other words, you would end up with something like this:

```
{
  {
    GroupId = 1,
    Part1 = "part1-1", // From SectionId == 7
    Part2 = "part1-2", // From SectionId == 3
    Part3 = "part1-3", // From SectionId == 1
  },
  {
    GroupId = 3,
    Part1 = "part3-1", // From SectionId == 7
    Part2 = "part3-2", // From SectionId == 3
    Part3 = "part3-3", // From SectionId == 1
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you map SectionId's to properties?

Comment: Is each group always going to have 3 parts, or could it vary?

Comment: It will always have the same number of parts and I have a list of SectionIds in my code (I have it as an Enum with predefined values, but it could be const).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
 from r in something
 group r by r.GroupId into g
 select new {
      GroupId = g.Key,
      Part1 = g.First(r => r.SectionId == 7).Content,
      Part2 = g.First(r => r.SectionId == 3).Content,
      Part3 = g.First(r => r.SectionId == 1).Content
 }
```

Comment: Great, they shut down our database for "maintenance" so I can't test it.  I had everything up to g.Key.  I keep forgetting g "contains" all the group's items, so this should work.  I think I'll use `.Single(...)` instead of `.First(...)` in case I unexpectedly have more than one result, in which case I prefer to quit instead of having "undefined" behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure if the `First` or `Single` calls will work in LINQ-to-SQL.

Comment: This is LINQ-to-Objects anyway, so no worries.  P.S. You seem to like LINQ since you show up in most of the LINQ question I have.  :)